# Posibility of solving large data problem using probability density function

Tags: probability-distributions, data-analysis

We are trying to solve a problem and right now it boils down to a complex data analysis problem.

Let's assume that $x$ is a random variable and we know the probability density function for that $(W(x))$.

Now we are going to perform the experiment for $10^{6}$ times.

The problem is, for each experiment, the instrument can't give us the exact $x$ value. Rather it will give us roughly $10^{2}$  $x$ values and say that the actual $x$ value will be one of those.

So, $10^{6}$ trails will give us $10^{6}$ data sets and each data set will contain roughly $10^{2}$ $x$ values in which only one value is the true value. Now in a straight forward way we can choose a random combination (where one $x$ value from each data set will be chosen randomly) and after plotting the histogram we can calculate statistical error for that and we can say for sure that the exact true combination will minimize statistical error. But I can't check all the combinations because the total number of combinations that I have to check is $({10^2})^{10^6}$.

Hence my question is, Is there any other way to approach this problem?

Image added here, https://ibb.co/eZcSGQ

Comment: Not to mention the computation required being infeasible, the storage to remember which combinations you've already tried would be infeasible. In other words, I think you need to give up on finding the "one" best combination. Instead look for a "good enough" combination. <br/>

Is each data set measuring the exact same thing as every other? Or is some parameter(s) varied between data sets? If former why so many trials?

<br/>

A possibility is to process a few data sets to determine whatever parameters you can, and for other datasets find the element in each that matches those parameters

Comment: Yes, each data set is measuring the same thing as other.

Comment: Yes, each data set is measuring the same thing as other. Can you please elaborate the last sentence? I can't understand what is parameter for a data set and how it will help me to reject redundant combinations.

Comment: Then every data set should have a value, say $C$, that is true value? If so start with first two data sets and find all  pairs that are same (or "close enough" to be considered same). Hopefully that is a lot fewer than 100 pairs. Call number of pairs, $N_2$. Then compare those pairs with third data and eliminate any pairs that aren't in third data set, and forming triples from remaining pairs. Call number of triples $N_3$. Then iterate until $N_i = 1$. Then check remaining data sets each have value consistent with i-tuple. If not then criteria for "close enough" must be relaxed.